# alfresco connect company database external

Tags: database, connection, external, alfresco

1. External database interface - Does Alfresco use point and click integration or is programming required to connect to the DB?
2. Can we use a 3rd party library like Google's zxing barcode reader to integrate with 
   Alfresco?

Regards
vish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

already exists a component for Alfresco Share which allow feature #1 with "zero code", in easy and flexible way.
Is available in Alfresco Addons http://addons.alfresco.com/addons/alfresco-metadbconnector-component.
Developed and maintained by VenziaIT (http://venzia.es).
We hope this help to the community.

Greetings!

Answer (score 2):

1. No point and click integration. It's build on Java, so you can write a custom Java class. The java class can be run scheduled, via a webscript, via workflow.
2. Of course, it's open source and fully build on Java, so integrate any 3d party solution into it. But you need to write everything yourself.

Answer (score 2):

1. What do you mean by external database interface? If we're talking about using external databases, then it's just a matter of [configuration](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Repository_Configuration#alfresco-global.properties_.28V3.2.2B.29).
2. It's generally not a problem to integrate 3rd party libraries. You just have to decide how to do that, e.g. using a custom [Java backed web script](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Java-backed_Web_Scripts_Samples) or a custom [action](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Custom_Actions).